# angularjs set focus on input when showed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
  <div class="information-box-header" ng-show="!item.editProductName" ng-click="editProductName($event, item)">
    {{item.ProductName}}
    <div class='door-price'>{{item.Price}} $</div>
</div>
<div class="information-box-header" ng-show="item.editProductName" >
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.ProductName" id="{{item.Id}}" value="{{item.ProductName}}" />
    <div class='door-price'>{{item.Price}} $</div>
</div>
```

When i click the first div i want the second div to show and the input to be focused. And when focus is lost i want it to change back so the first div is shown. How do i use focus in angular? tried with ng-focus but that didn't work since the input isn't shown right away?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `$timeout` service for setting the focus on 2nd div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , its working

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.item = {
    price:23,
    editProductName:false,
    Id:1,
    ProductName:''
    
  }
  $scope.onEdit = function(){
    $scope.item.editProductName = true;
  }
  $scope.onFocus = function(){
     console.log('onf');
  }
  $scope.onBlur = function(){
   $scope.item.editProductName = false;
  }
});

app.directive('ngFocus', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            scope.$watch( attrs.ngFocus, function ( val ) {
                if ( angular.isDefined( val ) && val ) {
                    $timeout( function () { element[0].focus(); } );
                }
            }, true);
            
            element.bind('blur', function () {
                if ( angular.isDefined( attrs.ngFocusLost ) ) {
                    scope.$apply( attrs.ngFocusLost );
                    
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="information-box-header" ng-show="!item.editProductName" ng-click="editProductName($event, item)">
    {{item.ProductName}}
    <div class='door-price'>{{item.Price}} $</div>
</div>
<div class="information-box-header" ng-show="item.editProductName" >
    <input type="text" ng-focus="item.editProductName"  ng-blur="onBlur()" ng-model="item.ProductName" id="{{item.Id}}" value="{{item.ProductName}}" />
    <div class='door-price'>{{item.Price}} $</div>
</div>
<button ng-click="onEdit()"  ng-show="!item.editProductName">Edit</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

On focus in to textbox I used directive from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ANfJZ/39/)